# ¿Como puedo cambiar de tabla con un select?

Tags: php, mysql

Necesito cambiar de tabla con un option al presionar el año , para que me muestren esos registros,hay alguna forma que podría producirlo? Estoy usando php y mysql , en mi mysql básicamente tengo una tabla con  un id ,nombre,edad , es una tabla de prueba para otro proyecto, De antemano Muchas Gracias!

```html
<select name="" id="">
        <option value="">Año</option>
        <option value="">2021</option>
        <option value="">2022</option>
        <option value="">2023</option>
        <option value="">2024</option>
        <option value="">2025</option>
    </select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes usar el evento onchange de javascript

```
<select id="combo1" name="combo1" onchange="reloadCombo(this.value);">
```

Y mediante una función en tu misma página y usando ajax , puedes recargar el combo con el nuevo contenido.

```
<script>
function reloadCombo(id) {
   $('#combo1').load('loadNewSel.php?pid='+id);
    }
</script>
```

Y en tu archivo loadNewSel.php, al cual le has pasado un parametro, usas dicho parametro para crear la nueva selección.

```php
<?php
$pid = $_GET['pid'];

echo <select id="combo1" name="combo1" onchange="reloadCombo(this.value);">
$query="SELECT * FROM tabla WHERE id=".$pid; 

if($result = mysqli_query($conn, $query)){
   if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0){
     while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
       echo "<option value=".$row['idcampo'].">".$row['nombreCampo']."</option>";
         }
      }
   }
echo "</select>"; 
?>
```

Este es un ejemplo incompleto de como podrías hacerlo, pero te puede servir de guía.

Comment: Gracias ! Lo probare!